# orchestration of spring rest webservices

Tags: microservices, spring-kafka, saga

If we have four spring REST Webservices say A B C D each of them has their own database.

How to implement distributed transaction using choreography based SAGA pattern with them?

Can I use Spring kafka + rest endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with SAGA but I would recommend Spiderwiz ([spiderwiz.org](http://spiderwiz.org)). It applies a similar event-driven paradigm, but its use is more straightforward and it eliminates the entire hassle of service discovery, pub-sub and other overhead thorns.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with **SAGA** database pattern. But it more preferable for complex work flow. Let me explain ,
first what is transaction mean ?
it means single unit of logic work and spread across multiple service in distributed system.Simply is that.when microservice world first you need to maintain **ACID**(atomic , consistent ,isolate and durable) properties. for that you need to **Cross Service Management Strategy**.

we can implement SAGA pattern using both choreography and orchestration way. If your system have very complex workflow then most suit model is orchestration.

Answer for Your question : if you using choreography method first we need Message Broker implementation. All the Transaction happen through in Message Broker.

and inside message broker you need to maintain TWO main Queues.one for Pass Operation Q and Other one for Failure operation Q.
when A completed their own operation then publish message to message broker and service B always listen that Message broker and Messages. like wise all service listen and their putting own transaction status message to the broker.
If Any service failed their own operation then Message publish to failure Q.

that is the scenario you need to implement.

This implementation depends on your system scale. and this method have major draw back :

- Cycle Dependencies risk (each service flow depend on others)

Benefits : choreography good for simple work flow and which have few service.
No single point failure.

Hope got ide about choreography SAGA pattern.

Thanks -dns-